# Custom 404 page not displayed - .htaccess issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a custom 404 page that I'm trying to display. It's located in my project root directory, as declared in my .htaccess file with the following line: `ErrorDocument 404 /mnt/www/new-site/app/404.html`. When I visit a non-existent link, I just get the default "Not Found" blank page with the message: `Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`. Using apache 2.4.4. .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^home /mnt/www/new-site/app/index.html
    RewriteRule ^login /mnt/www/new-site/app/login.php
    RewriteRule ^overview /mnt/www/new-site/app/solutions/overview.html
    RewriteRule ^technology /mnt/www/new-site/app/technology.html
    RewriteRule ^popular-data /mnt/www/new-site/app/popular-data.html
    RewriteRule ^about /mnt/www/new-site/app/about.html

    ErrorDocument 404 /mnt/www/new-site/app/404.html

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was the following line:

`ErrorDocument 404 /404.html`